# Understanding the scalability of Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang

It is said that thousands of processes can be spawned to do the similar task concurrently and Erlang is good at handling it. If there is more work to be done, we can simply and safely add more worker processes and that makes it scalable.

What I fail to understand is that if the work performed by each work is itself resource-intensive, how will Erlang be able to handle it? For instance, if entries are being made into a table by several sources and an Erlang application withing its hundreds of processes reads rows from the table and does something, this is obviously likely to cause resource burden. Every worker will try to pull a record from the table.
If this is a bad example, consider a worker that has to perform a highly CPU-intensive computation in memory. Thousands of such workers running concurrently will overwork the CPU.

Please rectify my understanding of the scalability in Erlang:
Erlang processes get time slices of the CPU only if there is work available for them. OS processes on the other hand get time slices regardless of whether they are idle.
The startup and shutdown time of Erlang processes is much lower than that of OS processes.

Apart from the above two points is there something about Erlang that makes it scalable?

Thanks,
Melvyn

Answer (score 3):

Scaling in Erlang is not automatic. The Erlang language and runtime provides some tools which makes it comparatively easy to write concurrent programs. If these are written correctly, then they are able to scale along several different dimensions:

- Parallel execution on multiple cores - since the VM understands to utilize them all.
- Capacity - Since you can have a process per task and they are light weight.

The biggest advantage is that Erlang processes are isolated, like in the OS, but unlike the OS the communication overhead is small. These two traits is what you want to exploit in Erlang programming.

The problem where you have a highly contended data resource is one to avoid if you are targeting high parallel execution. The best way to go around it is to split up your problem so it doesn't occur.

I have a blog post, http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.dk/2013/01/how-erlang-does-scheduling.html which describes in some more detail how the Erlang scheduler works. You may want to read that.